# Form that only allow for one person to choose each option

Tags: webapp-rec, google-forms

I need to create a form where people can select one of the options made available, and, once they do, that option becomes unavailable to anyone signing in afterwards. (Or where I can define the amount of "vacancies" in each option).

Google Forms doesn't have that option.
Does anyone know of an alternative platform where I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms may not have this option but you can use one of the free add-ons
Another way would be by using one of the add-ons found using the top right kebab menu (1) in the form:

[image: Where can I find add-ons for Google forms?]

- [Choice Eliminator 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/choice-eliminator-2/mnhoinjhhhafgieggnhjekliaodnkigj) or
- [Choice Eliminator light](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/choice-eliminator-lite/bnhfpdpmedfdodojojabjlpchcjemlml)

or similar add-ons would be your choice.

Once installed you can find them under the menu. (2)

[image: Where are my installed add-ons in Google forms?]

***Note***: One of the main caveats of what you are trying to achieve (either manually or through an add-on) is the time lapse between form submission and scripts execution. Most of the errors occurring are when submissions fall into that space in time resulting overlapping issues.

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.